# How to recognize if json key value is unavailable?

Tags: android, json

**JSON for Example:**

```
{
"example_key1": {
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3
},
"example_key2": [
    {
        "four": 4,
        "five": 5,
        "six": 6
    }
]
}
```

Right now i am consuming one method from web service.That method is returning some JSON data like the above JSON  example.

Here my problem is if some KEY values is missing from the JSON data, after consuming that method.(Say **"example_key2"** json value from the above json example is missing)

in the sense,

how can i recognize wether that key value is available or not?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String) for json array http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether particular key is available or not by using [**has()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) method

**For example:**

```
if(myJSONObject.has("one")) {
    num = myJSONObject.optString("one");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **has** method of JSONObject class

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

```
Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. The mapping may be NULL.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject("");
j.has("example_key2");
```